# get case insensitive key from list<map<String,String>>

Tags: java

I have a list> and now I want to search the key without considering case.
i.e. map.get(0).get("test") or map.get(0).get("TEST"). both result should give the value for key 'TESt'.

I am filling the List> list from other list> like below. There is no way to change the original map. Can anyone tell me how to add key with upper case?

mappedListHashed is List>
 accessLvlArray is List>

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : mappedListHashed) {
                accessLvlArray.add(map);
            }
```

Comment: can you standardize on the keys when you create your list?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The map.get() function required the key Object, and String TeST does not equal String TEsT. I'm not sure about other requirements, but you could first convert the complete map to a map with only lowercase keys. You should consider what happens when both TeST and TEsT are in the map, because one would override the other during the conversion.

Comment: You would have to create a case-insensitive wrapper. @Eran's solution is probably more practical.

Answer (score 3):

You could always put just lower case keys in your Map

```
list.get(0).put("tEst".toLowerCase(),"value");
```

and call

```
list.get(0).get("Test".toLowerCase())
```

in order to always search for the lower case version of the key.

If that's not an option, you can wrap your String key with a custom class that overrides `equals` and `hashCode` in a manner that ignores case.

Comment: Out of curiosity... How would this behave if both "TeST"  and " TEsT" are availlable as keys? Will it return the first result? This question is regarding wrappin the String key.

Comment: Ok then. is there any way to convert the key to uppercase in following code?for (HashMap<String, String> map : mappedListHashed) {
                    accessLvlArray.add(map);
                }

Comment: @JohannisK The idea is not to have "TeST" and "TEsT" keys in the Map, only "test" (hence `put("tEst".toLowerCase(),"value")`). Otherwise, neither "TeST" nor "TEsT" would be found when you search for "test".

Comment: @creativePro Who creates these `Map`s in the first place? Can't the code that creates the Maps make sure that the keys are either all lower case or upper case?

Comment: No Eran, I can't change the values in Map. It is filled in somewhere else and I just want to access it.

Comment: @creativePro In that case, assuming the case of the keys in that Map doesn't follow any convention, you may have to pre-process that Map and generate a new Map whose keys are all lower-case or upper-case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to override the put method:

```
public class myMap extends HashMap<String, String> {
@Override
public String put(String key, String value) {
   return super.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
}

public String get(String key) {
   return super.get(key.toLowerCase());
}
}
```

Comment: @creativePro:- Eran's answer is fine. Also did you try to create your Map like `Map<String, String> newMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`

Comment: I have a list<Map <String,String>>. How should I define a list with Map<String, String> newMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);?